# How do I limit one input to one output when there are two outputs for the one input? Database

Tags: database, ms-access

I always seem to get the confusing things so bear with me. I am currently dealing with standardized test scores. What I am doing is in Access, I am matching the score the student received with the percentage since percentage is what our school system uses to judge if certain students are eligible for certain services. My problem comes when a score of 39 can be 8 percent... and 7 percent.. I don't quite understand the logic in doing this, but I don't make standardized tests nor do I score them. Basically, I have two tables, one which contains the student's number and their score, and then another table that contains what score equals what percentage.

```
Score

Local_ID    Fall_Score
12121         39


Percentage

Fall_Score   Percentages
39                8
39                7
```

I have a query that combines these two, but the problem is, it makes two records. Is there a way that I can make Access chose just one of the records since I don't need two records in the output?

For instance, the output looks like

```
Combine

Local_ID   Fall_Score   Percentages
12121         39            8
12121         39            7
```

The Query looks something like this,

```
SELECT Local_ID, Fall_Score, Percentages
FROM Score LEFT JOIN Percentage ON Score.Fall_Score = Percentage.Fall_Score;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An average might be a good idea:

```
SELECT tr.Local_ID, tr.Fall_Score, Avg(tr.Percentages) AS AvgOfPercentages
FROM TableName As tr
GROUP BY tr.Local_ID, tr.Fall_Score;
```